# Finding distance between two gps points in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the method below (haversine) that returns the distance between two gps points. Table below is my dataframe.

When I apply the function on the dataframe using, I get the error "cannot convert the series to ". Not sure whether i am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 distdf1['distance'] = distdf1.apply(lambda x: haversine(distdf1['SLongitude'], distdf1['SLatitude'], distdf1['ClosestLong'], distdf1['ClosestLat']), axis=1)
```

Dataframe:

```
SLongitude  SLatitude   ClosestLong ClosestLat
0   -100.248093 25.756313   -98.220240  26.189491
1   -77.441536  38.991512   -77.481600  38.748722
2   -72.376370  40.898690   -73.662870  41.025640
```

Method:

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
"""
Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
"""
# convert decimal degrees to radians 
lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
# haversine formula 
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
km = 6367 * c
return km
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
distdf1.apply(lambda x: haversine(x['SLongitude'], x['SLatitude'], x['ClosestLong'], x['ClosestLat']), axis=1)
```